# EntityMapping add constraint

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Пытаюсь строить EntityMapping в Spring boot. Консоль возвращает следующую ошибку:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table order_list add constraint FKkmi3b4i3e2i97f0umqy911fq9 foreign key (product_id) references order (ord_id)]
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (ord_id)' at line 1

И такая же проблема касается двух других сущностей.
Не могу понять из-за чего вылазит ошибка...
Связь между сущностями Product и Order должна проходить через таблицу Order_list, в которой содержится идентификаторы сущностей Order и Product. У таблиц User и Product должна быть связь один ко многим.

База данных:
[image: база данных]
**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order")
public class Order {
  @Id
  private Long ord_id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="customer")
  private User customer;

  private String payment;
  private String delivery;
  private String status;
  private java.sql.Timestamp order_date;
  private String comment;



  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
  private Set<Product> productList;
```

**Product.java**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {
  @Id
  private Long prod_id;
  private String title;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="category")
  private Category category;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
  private Set<Custom_fields> custom_fields;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="manufacturer")
  private Manufacturer manufacturer;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
  private Set<Product_image> img;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
  private Set<Reviews> reviews;

  private Double sale;
  private Double price;
  private Long quantity;
  private java.sql.Timestamp date_added;
  private String description;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinTable(name="order_list",
          joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="order_id")},
          inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_id")})
  private Order order;
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
  @Id
  private Long user_id;
  private String address;
  private String email;
  private String login;
  private String name;
  private String password;
  private Long phone;
  private String role;
  private String surname;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private Set<Reviews> reviews;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
  private Set<Order> orders;
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в синтаксисе sql. как вы формировали таблицы? пришлите запрос на создание таблиц. тоже хотелось бы посмотреть.

Comment: попробуйте как вариант там где mappedBy написать название таблицы в верхнем регистре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` - это ключевое слово SQL, таблицу или её поле так назвать нельзя. Измените имя таблицы на что-нибудь другое:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order_table")
public class Order {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Переименовала таблицу и все прошло. Спасибо большое за совет.